# GetExternalLoginInfo() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to use an Azure AD to authenticate users. Everything seems to be working fine until the redirect to `RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs`. For some reason the `Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo()` method keeps returning null, causing the application to redirect. Since it redirects here it's failing to create a new Identity User which is causing me issues further down the line.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    // app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    var openIDOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    };
    openIDOptions.Scope = "openid profile email";
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIDOptions);
}
```

Here's the `Page_Load()` from RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    // Process the result from an auth provider in the request
    ProviderName = IdentityHelper.GetProviderNameFromRequest(Request);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderName))
    {
        RedirectOnFail();
        return;
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            RedirectOnFail();
            return;
        }
        var user = manager.Find(loginInfo.Login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Apply Xsrf check when linking
            var verifiedloginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo(IdentityHelper.XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (verifiedloginInfo == null)
            {
                RedirectOnFail();
                return;
            }

            var result = manager.AddLogin(User.Identity.GetUserId(), verifiedloginInfo.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            email.Text = loginInfo.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

I saw a couple of answers related to cookies but these don't seem to fix the issue for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement Azure AD external login using OpenID Connect with ASP.NET identity .You need to enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user and use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider . Please refer to below configuration:

```
// Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
             //app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
       //app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);



        var openIDOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
        openIDOptions.Scope = "openid profile email";
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIDOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out when I get to the office on monday. Will let you know then.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks.